# Structure of Android app (java) continuously scanning for Bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to create an application that will continuously scan for other BT devices while the process is active (not killed).
The main idea is to scan for devices that are within the custom range (signal strength that I hope I can get from RSSI) and to log those occurances to a database in cloud.
I want to use a tabbedActivity:
1 tab - Current visible devices (needs to be refreshed every x seconds)
2 tab - history of ocurrances that has been sent to the database during current session (I have to implement some methods to eleminate duplicates etc.)

The question is how the structure of my application should look like?

Where should I put whole BT thing? As I suppose it shouldn't be in the MainActivity, because it can lagg the whole application. Should I use a service class? Another thread? The same question applies to the part of the program, which sends info to database.

Any sugestions regarding the internal structure would be great.
Any tips regarding energy consumption also.